# Counting six-letter strings over $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ containing a single $a$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider all strings whose letters belong to the set:

$A = \{ a, b, c, d, e\}$

How many strings of length $6$ are there that contain exactly one $a$?

Attempt:

Since we are only using $\frac{4}{5}$ letters for the rest of the string,

There are $1* 4^5$ strings that contain exactly one $a$.

Book answer: $6 * 4^5$

What am I doing wrong? Where does the six come from?

Comment: The answers below are correct.  But I just wanted to add that you should feel very encouraged, because you were on the right track.  Keep it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strings, the order matters. So, you can put the one "a" in any one of the six positions. There are $4^5$ ways to fill up the rest. Hence, you multiply $4^5$ by 6.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a$ is in the first slot. Then we can put any of the four other letters in the 2nd slot. Same with the third slot, etc. There are six slots. So for $a$ in slot one, we have $4*4*4*4*4=4^5$ ways of arranging the other letters.

Now suppose $a$ is in slot two. By the same logic, there are again $4^5$ way to arrange the other letters.

Since there are six places to put $a$, we repeat this calculation six times: $4^5+4^5+4^5+4^5+4^5+4^5=6*4^5.$